# Sobrescrever CSS de compontente calendar no Richfaces

Tags: css, jsf, rich-faces

Estou usando um componente *calendar* porém somente a data (omitindo a hora), e sobrescrevendo o *CSS* pra reduzir o tamanho em tela. Segue abaixo:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{_sessao.dtSessao}" showFooter="false" enableManualInput="true" locale="pt_BR" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" style="width:80px;"/>
```

Porém, não está aplicando.

Até aonde sei, em *JSF*, *Primefaces* e similares, está certo.

Comment: qual a versão do richfaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localizei a solução, que era relativamente simples, mas como eu não utilizo o *Richfaces* tive que ver os componentes que ele contém.

Ao invés de utilizar:

```
<rich:calendar ... style="width:80px;"/>
```

Verifiquei que existe a tag *inputStyle* que resolveu diretamente no componente, exatamente como o *style* faz no *JSF*, ficando então:

```
<rich:calendar ... inputStyle="width:80px;"/>
```

Verifiquei e existem outros casos parecidos no Richfaces, então é interessante verificar cada componente pois a solução pode ser similar.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o ideal era fazer essa modificação de script em um css. Pois esse componente gera diversos codigos HTML para o efeito.

de uma olhada na [documentação](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html#d0e29993) e verifique a parte que você deseja alterar o estilo.

Também verifique nos estilos aplicados se não tem nenhum outro estilo sendo sobreescrito.

Lembre-se css com !important tem precedencias até sobre estilos do atribulo style.

### Exemplo:

Tendo o calendario

```
<rich:calendar value="#{calendarBean.selectedDate}" id="calendar" locale="#{calendarBean.locale}"
  popup="#{calendarBean.popup}" datePattern="#{calendarBean.pattern}"
  showApplyButton="#{calendarBean.showApply}" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px"
  style="width:200px" disabled="#{calendarBean.disabled}">
</rich:calendar>
```

E um css de alteração de fonte:

```
    .rich-calendar-tool-btn {
      font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    }
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas vi a solução que postei abaixo, que acaba sendo mais simples.

Comment: Sim. só não é uma boa pratica misturar o css junto ao código.

Comment: concordo contigo dependendo da situação, pois como é um ajuste simples, me parece mais interessante agir assim do que criar um _CSS_ à parte, mas em casos que requerem mais customização ou aplicação em diversos lugares, realmente é mais adequado para deixar o código mais limpo. No meu caso preferi diretamente no componente pois ele é utilizado em outros pontos da tela, que não necessitavam desta alteração.